# Serenity tests run using mvn verify do not have a pie chart

Tags: java, maven, serenity-bdd

Below is the step class which is used to run the test step defs

```
package serenity.page;

import net.serenitybdd.core.annotations.findby.By;
import net.thucydides.core.annotations.DefaultUrl;
import net.thucydides.core.pages.PageObject;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

@DefaultUrl("http://in-air-aciscoe1/webcoe2")
public class LoginPage extends PageObject {
    public void enterUsername(String username) {
        WebElement txtUsername = find(By.name("username"));

    typeInto(txtUsername, username);
}
public void enterPassword(String password) {
    WebElement txtPassword = find(By.name("password"));
    typeInto(txtPassword, password);

}
public void clickOnSubmit() {
    WebElement button = getDriver().findElement(By.xpath(".//*    [@id='btnLogin']"));
button.click();
}
```

I have got all the java class file in the test folder and not in the main folder

package serenity.stepDefinitions;

```
import cucumber.api.java.en.And;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;
import net.serenitybdd.core.annotations.findby.By;
import net.thucydides.core.annotations.Step;
import net.thucydides.core.annotations.Steps;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import serenity.runTests.LoginSteps;


public class LoginFeatureStepDefinitions {

    WebDriver driver;

    @Steps
    LoginSteps loginSteps;


    @When("^I should see the text element 'username'$")
    public void iShouldSeeTheTextElementUsername() /**throws Throwable**/ {
        loginSteps.enterUsername("arushi");
    }

    @Then("^I should see the text element 'password'$")
    public void iShouldSeeTheTextElementPassword() /**throws Throwable**/ {
        loginSteps.enterPassword("Pass-123");
    }

    @And("^I click the 'Login' button$")
    public void iClickTheLoginButton() {
    loginSteps.clickOnSubmit();
        }

    @And("^I should see the text element 'firstname'$")
    public void iShouldSeeTheTextElementFirstname() /**throws Throwable**/ {
        driver.findElement(By.name("firstname")).sendKeys("Arushi");

    }
}
```

Above is the step definition class that I have used.

```
package serenity.runTests;

import net.thucydides.core.annotations.Step;
import net.thucydides.core.steps.ScenarioSteps;
import serenity.page.LoginPage;
public class LoginSteps extends ScenarioSteps {

    private LoginPage loginPage; //automatically instantiated


    @Step
    public void enterUsername(String username) {
        loginPage.enterUsername(username);
    }

    @Step
    public void enterPassword(String password) {
        loginPage.enterPassword(password);
    }

    @Step
    public void clickOnSubmit() {
        loginPage.clickOnSubmit();
    }
}
```

Above is the step class I used for the tests
And I run the test runner using CucumberWithSerenity.class

Comment: What is your specific question/problem?

Comment: So I have a serenity-cucumber test pack and I used maven to import the libraries.
All the step definitions and other java classes are in place.
So since I am new to serenity I have to generate the test report however everytime I run mvn verify the build is run however the test report does not generate the pie chart nor re there any automated test run counts.

Comment: try 'mvn clean verify aggregate'. also have you followed the maven pom which is suggested by the serenity team. ref.- http://thucydides.info/docs/serenity-staging/#_building_serenity_projects_in_maven

Comment: Have the same problem too with windows 7 and gradle